# Magento 2 Upgrade Process Stuck

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.3. Copy and paste the file and run upgrade command but process stuck process not progress process.

> only show last is Schema creation/updates:

Following is screenshot:
[image]